# Use case expression to get count and percentage for each condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want an output similar to the table below where I can get the count and percentage  from a query using the Case expression. The numbers in the table are just for illustration purposes.

| AgeGroup | Count | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Silent | 1 | 10% |
| Boomers | 2 | 20% |
| Generation | 1 | 10% |
| Millennial | 4 | 40% |
| Generation Z | 2 | 20% |

I ran the following query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE
        WHEN birth_year between 1928 and 1945 THEN 'Silent'
        WHEN birth_year between 1946 and 1964 THEN 'Boomers'
        WHEN birth_year between 1965 and 1980 THEN 'Generation X'
        WHEN birth_year between 1981 and 1996 THEN 'Millennial'
        WHEN birth_year between 1997 and 2012 THEN 'Generation Z'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END) as 'AgeGroup'
    FROM CombinedTable
```

The output gives me the total count which is not what I want.

**Note:** *I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017*

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: How have I not provided that?

Comment: I think you've provided your desired output, but no sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by that `CASE` expression. You can place it in a `CROSS APPLY` to avoid having to repeat it.

> `VALUES` returns a virtual table, and if you use `CROSS APPLY` you can join it onto each row, while being able to insert values from previously referenced tables

```sql
SELECT
  v.AgeGroup, 
  COUNT(*) AS Count,
  COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS Percentage
FROM CombinedTable ct
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CASE
        WHEN birth_year between 1928 and 1945 THEN 'Silent'
        WHEN birth_year between 1946 and 1964 THEN 'Boomers'
        WHEN birth_year between 1965 and 1980 THEN 'Generation X'
        WHEN birth_year between 1981 and 1996 THEN 'Millennial'
        WHEN birth_year between 1997 and 2012 THEN 'Generation Z'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END
)) v(AgeGroup)
GROUP BY
  v.AgeGroup;
```

---

This is also more easily done with a join

> In this case, we construct a virtual table of possible options, and join it to each row in the normal way

```sql
SELECT
  ISNULL(v.AgeGroup, 'Other') AS AgeGroup, 
  COUNT(*) AS Count,
  COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS Percentage
FROM CombinedTable ct
LEFT JOIN (VALUES
    (1928,1945,'Silent'),
    (1946,1964,'Boomers'),
    (1965,1980,'Generation X'),
    (1981,1996,'Millennial'),
    (1997,2012,'Generation Z')
) v(StartYear, EndYear, AgeGroup) ON tc.birth_year BETWEEN v.StartYear AND v.EndYear
GROUP BY
  ISNULL(v.AgeGroup, 'Other');
```

Comment: It worked! I used the JOIN option you provided.  Is this essentially kind of like a self join? Would appreciate if you could elaborate on the query a little more, thanks again.

Comment: `VALUES` returns a virtual constructed table. `APPLY` can refer to previously referenced tables, so in that case it is kind of like a self-join, but without the cost of an extra lookup. In the second version, a normal join is used.