# How do I group in CASE function in SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by, case

```sql
    SELECT u.shopid,i.item_stock,i.item_ctime,
        Case
            When i.item_stock < 10 then 'Group 0'
            when i.item_stock between '10' and '99' then 'Group 1'
            when i.item_stock between '100' and '999' then 'Group 2'
            when i.item_stock >= 1000 then 'Group 3'
        Else 'None'
    End as Grouping
  FROM [dfgsdfg].[dbo].[user_profile$] as u
  join item_profile$ as i
  on i.shopid = u.shopid
  where (i.item_ctime between '2017-01-01' and '2017-05-31')
```

This is the result I get after I have tried many queries
[image]

But the desired table would be like this

```
    GROUP       Number of shops
    0           xxx
    1           xxx
    2           xxx
    3           xxx
```

How do I get a table like this i have tried and finding about this for a while now

Comment: It seems you know you need to use a `GROUP BY` here, but you haven't actually used one. It seems like none of the columns apart from the one you've aliased `Grouping` are relevant here. What you want is that `Grouping` column, a `COUNT` and then the appropriate `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Larnu I have tried to [group by] using the [grouping] column but it said [invalid column named grouping] which I have created through case function

Comment: Because you can't reference a column by it's alias (defined in the `SELECT`) in the `GROUP BY`; you need to repeat the expression or use a devired table.

Comment: Does this answer your questioner? [SQL - using alias in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841295/sql-using-alias-in-group-by)

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out, I'm new to SQL so its pretty confusing it would be great if I could see how to write it. Thank you

Comment: select case...end as grouping, count(shopid) as [number of shops] from yourtable group by case..end

Comment: Do i have to edit this in my query or create another subquery

Comment: I have manage to figure it out now thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use case expression to get count and percentage for each condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69701126/use-case-expression-to-get-count-and-percentage-for-each-condition)